# How to know current encoding in Firefox?

Tags: browser, encoding

I use to on website which have some issues with local chars encoding ,but for one second it switch it up to the normal encoding, but I cant detect where/from encoding was made. Is it possible to see at least current encoding in Firefox/ or maybe Chrome?

Answer (score 1):

Right Click on Page -> Show Page Information (UTF-8 in this case)

[image: FF Page Information]

Or more detailed, if you want, from command line using Curl:

Linux, Mac, BSD
`curl -s -D - http://superuser.com/questions/1035382/how-to-know-current-encoding-in-firefox/1035397#1035397 -o /dev/null`

Windows
`curl -s -D - http://superuser.com/questions/1035382/how-to-know-current-encoding-in-firefox/1035397#1035397 -o nul`

```
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Date: Thu, 04 Feb 2016 01:38:01 GMT
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
    Transfer-Encoding: chunked
    Connection: keep-alive
    Set-Cookie: __cfduid=df9847c333782c1258978f0ef728911591454549881; expires=Fri, 03-Feb-17 01:38:01 GMT; path=/; domain=.superuser.com; HttpOnly
    Cache-Control: public, no-cache="Set-Cookie", max-age=60
    Expires: Thu, 04 Feb 2016 01:39:01 GMT
    Last-Modified: Thu, 04 Feb 2016 01:38:01 GMT
    Vary: *
    X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
    X-Request-Guid: fa91961b-e43e-268b-afcb-9650f78b7efb
    Set-Cookie: prov=63457e67-0f52-42c2-817d-4c4def77515e;        domain=.superuser.com; expires=Fri, 01-Jan-2055 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
    Server: cloudflare-nginx
    CF-RAY: 26f2a75766132d2f-TXL
```